# DJVU to PDF conversion application

Tags: pdf, conversion, djvu

Which program can convert a book from DJVU to PDF format. Please advise one's you have tried yourself.

Comment: Linux? OS X? Windows? web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the PDF virtual printers will do this - I use [pdfFactory](http://fineprint.com/pdf/).

Comment: I tried printing to PDF with the printer that comes with Adobe Acrobat. The generated pdf file is just too large (a 5mb djvu file converted to a 150 mb pdf file) and my Kindle gets stuck playing it, so it's no use. Do you think pdfFactory would be any better?

Comment: @becko - it can be better, because Acrobat is one of biggest crap of Adobe

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I recommend [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), an open source software. You simply print it to the PDFCreator printer.

Comment: [Please read my comment to the answer above] ... Do you think PDFCreator would be any better?

Answer (score -1):

First, since PDF is a proprietary format, it's always better to always use Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Second, for your case:

1. I advise to install [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) as with it you can open many other documents types beside those of **Djvu** & **PDF**, and it's truly **light weight**.
2. If you have already installed Acrobat Reader (*or similar*) your can Print/Export your **Djvu** document using the virtual printer that comes with Acrobat Reader (*or similar*).

**PS:**

1. This method will convert your **Djvu** pages to bitmaps, so forget about maintaining text & etc, and expect that the file size will increase dramatically.
2. PDF is optimised for vector graphics while **Djvu** applies an algorithm for compressing images far below a **JPG** can achieve ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu)).